# How to link to sections in a LaTeX document from a picture in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, links

I am trying to use work from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95392/43245) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120631/43245) to create something that looks similar to the following:

[image]

However, I would like to be able to actually link to the sections in the document from the pictures in the `TOC` (that is, the pictures underneath the sections in the `TOC` should have red boundary boxes just like the other sample pictures, indicating an active link). The code I attempted to use was as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,linkcolor=black,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\addstufftotoc}[2][toc]{% \addimagetotoc[<toc>]{<stuff>}
  \addtocontents{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Click to learn more:\\

  \hyperref[sec:A]{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}\qquad
  \hyperref[sec:B]{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-b}}\qquad
  \hyperref[sec:C]{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-c}}

\section{Section A}\label{sec:A}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-a}\par}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Section B}\label{sec:B}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-b}\par}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Section C}\label{sec:C}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\hyperref[sec:C]{\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-c}}\par}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The attempt for Section C (trying to use the work from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120631/43245)) is where the error is thrown:

`! Use of \\addstufftotoc doesn't match its definition.`

Is there a way to modify the definition of `addstufftotoc` or some other method to produce my desired result (i.e., have pictures in the `TOC` that link to sections in the document)?

Comment: `\hyperref[sec:C]{\protect\includegraphics{...}}` is a possible solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\includegraphics` command has to be protected for `\hyperref` as well, that's all.

Use

```
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\hyperref[sec:C]{\protect\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-c}}\par}
```

to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,linkcolor=black,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\addstufftotoc}[2][toc]{% \addimagetotoc[<toc>]{<stuff>}
  \addtocontents{#1}{#2}%
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Click to learn more:\\

\hyperref[sec:A]{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}\qquad
\hyperref[sec:B]{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-b}}\qquad
\hyperref[sec:C]{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-c}}

\section{Section A}\label{sec:A}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-a}\par}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Section B}\label{sec:B}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-b}\par}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Section C}\label{sec:C}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\hyperref[sec:C]{\protect\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-c}}\par}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Some explanations:

`\includegraphics` is defined as

```
\def\includegraphics{%
  \@ifstar
    {\Gin@cliptrue\Gin@i}%
    {\Gin@clipfalse\Gin@i}}
```

i.e. the command itself has no arguments, but leaves it to internal commands as `\Gin@i` etc. which itself have optional arguments  -- this is fragile and `\hyperref{\includegraphics...}` breaks apart, not seeing the full list of arguments then. In order to prevent this, `\protect` must be used.

Another way is to use the `\robustify` command from the `etoolbox` package and saying `\robustiy{\includegraphics}` in the preamble of the document -- this will make `\includegraphics` robust and `\protect` isn't needed any longer (for `\includegraphics`)

Comment: Thanks a lot--that's exactly what I needed. Anything I could read to give more explanation behind your answer (i.e., what needs to be protected and all that)? Or is that an overly general question (i.e., read the `hyperref` package, look at the TeXbook, etc.)?

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: I'll add an explanation

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: See the update, please

Comment: That helps a bit. Thanks for the added explanation!

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: Only a bit? ;-) There's a general rule: If a command has moving arguments (i.e. the command itself has no arguments, but calls sub commands that treat the argument) this command is fragile then and needs `\protect` as soon it is nested into the argument of another command. This is true for many commands and one has to know, which commands have moving arguments. For example, `\chapter`, `\section` etc. are usual suspects, but `\includegraphics` as well.